# How to pause the current state of mapview in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I have map application in which I have four buttons for Zoom In, Zoom Out, Play/Pause and Stop buttons. when zooming button is clicked map zoom in and when zoom out button is clicked map zooms out. On clicking play/pause button the user can pause the current journey and the state of the button changes to pause and when user once again clicks on the pause button the state of the button changes to play.

On clicking stop button ,the user can end the current journey. I have done with zoomin and zoomout buttons but I am confused on how to start and stop the current journey of the user.

Comment: what do you mean by journey of user? does it have anything to do with the current location updated as user travels?

Comment: yes as the user travels the direction is mapped on the map i.e is the journey of user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)pauseButtonPressed
{
if(!isPaused)
{
mapview.showsUserLocation = NO; // if you want to stop showing user location
[yourLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];// If you use CLLocationManager to get location
isPaused = YES;
}
else
{
mapview.showsUserLocation = YES; 
[yourLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
isPaused = NO;
}
```

Comment: yes this is to stop the current journey but how to pause the journey for some time

Comment: use `[yourLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];` when you want to start again